# How do I get a serial number by Receiver Application on Chromecast

Tags: chromecast

I'm developing a Receiver Application on the Chromecast.
I want to use a serial number in order to limit the viewing on multiple devices at the same time.

How do I get a serial number by Receiver Application on Chromecast.
I could not find it from the developer's guide.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As part of the device discovery message exchange, device-desc.xml is received by the sender app which has UDN value. This UDN is a UUID and I assume you can use it to uniquely identify the device and may not even need the serial no for your purpose.

Comment: It looks like it's impossible to retrieve device-desc.xml through JS because of cross-domain XHR restrictions. The Sender App loading the XML during discovery exchange will not help the OP make his Receiver App find the UDN.

Answer (score 5):

The serial number is not exposed programmatically.