# Chromecast receiver window.deviceInfo.deviceId = serial number

Tags: chromecast, google-cast

I have noticed that there is an object `window.deviceInfo` that contains the chromecast receiver serial number, where `deviceId` matches the serial number:

```
window.deviceInfo = {
    buildVersion: '16278',
    deviceId: '3923536d1ITU'
}
```

This is not mentioned in the [Chromecast Receiver API documentation](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/reference/receiver/), and it has been previously stated that the serial number is not exposed.

[How do I get a serial number by Receiver Application on Chromecast](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21153049/how-do-i-get-a-serial-number-by-receiver-application-on-chromecast)

Can I rely on this value to as a unique identifier for the Chromecast receiver device, or are there plans to remove or change this value?

Answer (score 0):

**FALSE ALARM!**

This information is only available to the Chromecast home screen application, via a locally stored Javascript file

`chrome://home/strings.js`

If you try and load this in a custom receiver application:

`<script src="chrome://home/strings.js">`

you get an insecure content error

`The page at 'https://my.receiver-app.com' was loaded over HTTPS, but ran insecure content from 'chrome://home/strings.js': this content should also be loaded over HTTPS.`