# Is there a way to get a unique id to identify a Chromecast device?

Tags: android, chromecast

I'm developing a game for Chromecast. I was thinking about monetizing it and realize that there is a new way to get an "ads removed premium feature".

You pay for the option to remove ads in all kind of devices connected to the Chromecast app. This will be useful for party games: pay one, remove all device ads.

But, to do this i need some way to identify a Chromecast. Of course, my first option was the device id, but this answered question block that way:

[How do I get a serial number by Receiver Application on Chromecast](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21153049/how-do-i-get-a-serial-number-by-receiver-application-on-chromecast)

Is there some way to get an unique identifier for a Chromecast device?.

Comment: "I'm developing a game for Chromecast" -- no, you are developing a game for an Android or iOS device that happens to display its output on a Chromecast. "Is there some way to get an unique identifier for a Chromecast device?." -- why aren't you just using in-app purchases for the device that is actually running the game?

Comment: Well, i think my javascript on a Chromecast receiver app not agree with that "no Chromecast game" ;-). Yep, i'm using in-app purchases, but that doesn't solve the problem. I need to identify the Chromecast when the player buy the premium feature to remove ads to all connected mobiles.

Answer (score 2):

No, you do not have a unique identifier exposed and that is by design. To achieve what you want, why don't you use the id of the user who has paid for your service? So if user logs into her account on her phone, directly or indirectly, and then casts to a Cast device; at that time, you know the identity of the user and whether she should see ads or not and as part of the initialization of the receiver, you can instruct it (via your handheld device) that ads should be there or not. Maybe I am missing something?

Comment: No ads to the group connected, whatever Cast device he connects. I was trying to limit that behaviour to only the first Cast device, the one that is casting to when payment is proccessed.

Comment: Just remember that is not the model that people are used to for CC; if you have an account with Netflix, you can use it on any CC that you connect to; so restricting it to a particular CC device is not a good idea in general; but that is just a side note and it is up to you as the app developer to decide what is best for you and your customers. To reiterate, we intentionally don't expose such id (which would have been the serial number, for example) to the receiver, mainly due to privacy concerns.

Comment: Thanks Ali, i will change my mind and try it that other way. Thanks!

Comment: I'm a little stubborn ;-). Imagine this: a group of people come to my house to play a CC quiz game. Each one has a casting device. As i am a good host, i pay for a premium feature that remove ads forever for that game in all devices i use to connect to that CC game. Later, my kids are playing with their own devices and no ads for them too. I think this is a different kind of scenario(different from netflix service) that will increase usability for that users. I know, there is no way to get an unique id for CC ;-), but in this scenario you have to pay with each mobile to get the same result.

Comment: I'm not sure what your conclusion is. In Netflix model, subscription is tied to an account. Then any device that logs into that account can play on any screen, including CC; if I have 2 CC devices, one in my living room and one in bedroom, I wouldn't like to be asked to pay two subscription; CC is just a means to deliver the same content on a different screen so if I have an account that allows me to play a content on my phone, then I should have the capability to watch that on a larger screen, with the very same account. As I said, it is up to the developer.

Comment: Ok, you're right...I'm sorry to be so stubborn ;-).

Comment: Not at all, it is a good discussion to have and there might be very good reasons for an app to try to do things differently based on their business model; the important thing is that one has to have a very good reason to do something that goes against a user's common perception. Enjoy casting!

Comment: I'm considering building a product where the end user has multiple Chromecasts and what's being displayed on them, will depend on which one it is. To this effect, I think wanting to be able to read some kind of device ID, is totally legitimate.

Comment: It could be very useful for debugging an individual device, e.g. trying to figure out if a problem is hardware or software related.